# later js: every year on same date wrong response

Tags: node.js, laterjs

I am trying to create a schedule in laterjs for next 10 occurrence at a specified time for every year.

Following is my code:

```
var later = require("later")

var startdate = new Date();
var curr_time = "12:09:10";

later.date.localTime();   
var s = later.parse.recur().every(1).year().on(curr_time).time();
later.schedule(s).next(5, startdate);
```

Response is :

```
Array (5 items)
 0: Thu Aug 17 2017 12:09:10 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
 1: Fri Aug 18 2017 12:09:10 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
 2: Sat Aug 19 2017 12:09:10 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
 3: Sun Aug 20 2017 12:09:10 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
 4: Mon Aug 21 2017 12:09:10 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

please tell me, where i am doing wrong.

Comment: What's the question and what's the result you want?

Comment: i want to schedule a task on a particular date & time on yearly basis. But it's showing same year for all next  5 schedules in response.